# Syntax error on LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT w1.Id
FROM Wills w1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Wills w2
WHERE w1.Id = w2.Id + 1
AND w1.Tmp > w2.Tmp
```

With the query, I want to compare rows with adjacent `Id`s. I want to select those that have a greater `Tmp` field than their predecessor.

However, I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error Message:
Line 3: SyntaxError: near 'WHERE w1.Id = w2.Id + 1
AND w1.Tmp > w2.Tmp'
```

I don't have much experience with SQL and MySQL.
Did I do the join incorrectly?

Comment: How can you guarantee that ids are contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT w1.Id
FROM Wills w1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Wills w2 ON w1.Id = w2.Id + 1
and  w1.Tmp > w2.Tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

You *need* to put the conditions in the `ON` clause rather than a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT w1.Id
FROM Wills w1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     Wills w2
     ON w1.Id = w2.Id + 1 AND w1.Tmp > w2.Tmp;
```

If either condition is in the `WHERE`, then the `LEFT JOIN` will be turned into an `INNER JOIN`.